# AWK counting back

Tags: awk

I have a list of domains matched and piped in through grep with various length but all match the last three records. I'm trying to output all of the non-qualified sub-domains.

I have:

```
awk -F'.' -v OFS='.' '{$(NF-3)=$(NF-2)=$(NF-1)=""; print $0}'
```

my output leaves trailing ...... on the output

Thanks

Comment: source:
site.subdomain.xyz.com
site.sub.subdomain.xyz.com

results:
site...
site.sub....

desired results:
site
site.sub

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example of your input data and your desired output.

Comment: Note `{print $0}` is the default behaviour of awk, so you can write a true condition instead: `1` will do the same. Also, `{print}` is the same as `{print $0}`, so you can omit the reference to `$0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting them:

```
$ awk -F'.' 'sub(FS $(NF-2) FS $(NF-1) FS $NF,"")' <<<"www.cse.iitb.ac.in"
www.cse
```

I'm not sure why this works and your method doesn't, but according to this [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/302542666-post5.html) post, that's the way.

Answer (score 2):

When producing output, `awk` obeys the current value of `NF`.  If you want to eliminate the last three fields, just reduce `NF` by three, such as via `NF-=3`:

```
awk -F. -v OFS=. '{NF-=3; print $0}'
```

Using this with your sample input:

```
$ echo $'site.subdomain.xyz.com\nsite.sub.subdomain.xyz.com' | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{NF-=3; print $0}'
site
site.sub
```

Incidentally, a period, `.`, is not a shell-active character.  So, it does not need quoting.

Comment: That is much cleaner. Just curious, does setting the OFS to '.' have any effect here?

Comment: Thank you.  Curiously, yes it does: without `OFS=.`, I get space-separated output.  This differs from the output using your approach.  I suspect that the difference is that your approach operates on the input line as a whole and therefore does not trigger `awk` into reformatting with a new `OFS`.